# Silverlight -- Debug.WriteLine() not working for a long string

Tags: c#, silverlight, debugging, windows-phone-7

I have a longish (3626 chars) string.  When I have in my code

```
Debug.WriteLine(myString);
```

it only writes the first part.  How can I tell it to write the whole thing?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the Debug.WriteLine that's limiting the text - or could it be VS.Net that's truncating some output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit to how long the string can be when your use Debug.WriteLine(). What you could do is simply break your string up and display each block individually.

Comment: OK . . . seems like a weird limitation . . . is there another simple way to print the whole thing to a place I can see it?

Comment: You could use a StreamWriter and output it to a text file on your computer. Presumably this is only for when you're debugging, and not for production, so that should let you output the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

The default character limit per line with `Debug.WriteLine` is **715** characters. If you want to print more than that, you will have to split the existing string in multiple lines, considering the existing threshold. You could also use a third-party logging framework to log the data outside the standard trace listener.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the string to object and it won't truncate it, eg:

Debug.WriteLine((object)getlongstring(), "test");